# map returning null in Vf page

Tags: visualforce, map

I have a map, I print both the key and map in the VF page and it prints both, but When I print map[key], it doesn't print anything. What could be the issue?

```
        key - {!selectedPlcId}  (returns value)
        map - {!plcMap}(returns value)
        map[key] -{!plcMap[selectedPlcId]}(returns nothing)
```

-----Edit----

Adding the output values

```
        key - {!selectedPlcId} - a0Qi0000006h01bEAA
        map - {!plcMap} - {a0Qi0000006h01bEAA=[ts2__Placement__c (Name:PLC-021315-00784, RecordTypeId:012i0000000q088AAA, CurrencyIsoCode:USD, ts2__Start_Date__c:Mon Feb 02 00:00:00 GMT 2015, ts2__Client__r:[Account (Name:Back Office Test Company, RecordTypeId:012i0000000q07iAAA, CurrencyIsoCode:USD, Id:001i000001EFTR7AAP)], ts2__Client__c:001i000001EFTR7AAP, ts2__Job__c:a0Ki000000Bpg2NEAR, Id:a0Qi0000006h01bEAA, ts2__Job__r:[ts2__Job__c (Name:Test Back Office Job Order, RecordTypeId:012i0000000q080AAA, CurrencyIsoCode:USD, Id:a0Ki000000Bpg2NEAR)], tc9_ti__Award_Master__c:a3Gi0000000TZWUEA4, tc9_ti__Time_Sheets__r:common.api.soap.wsdl.QueryResult@1, ts2__End_Date__c:Tue Feb 03 00:00:00 GMT 2015)]} 

        map[key] -{!plcMap[selectedPlcId]}(returns nothing)

 I get this 'common.api.soap.wsdl.QueryResult@1' in the map
```

Comment: Map keys are case-sensitive.. Are you sure that the key is present in the map? Also try using the `map.containsKey(key)` in apex and see what it returns?

Comment: Hi Sameer, if there is no key, I would've received Map key not found error, right?

Comment: Start by checking if the key is present in the map. Use map.contansKey(key) in your Apex to be 100% sure (as theGreatDanton said).

Comment: Riadh, again I would've received Map key not found error right?

Comment: Yes, if there is no key that matches the one you are using you will get a key not found exception

Comment: @akash: True, one would get the `Key not found` exception.

Comment: There is no such exception in Apex. It is not an error to try to retrieve a map key that does not exist, the return value is just null.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Apex Code won't give such an error, but Visualforce *will* crash if the key isn't found: `Map key value not found in map
Error is in expression '{!values[key]}' in component <apex:page> in page testmap`. I just tested this for proof.

Comment: @akash I want to help you, but we don't have any actual code snippets here. Something is amiss, but clearly the map is populated correctly, or you'd crash. Can you please update your question with more code?

Comment: Are your Map keys `Strings` or `Ids`? Please post controller code.

Comment: its a map<Id, sObject> . I'm not in a position to share the code. But as for my last edit, this is the output I received.